# Can I cut the recessed lighting housing rails to make them fit in joists 12" apart?

Tags: lighting, led, recessed-lighting

I have this [guy](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000HM5NEO) -- I got new work since the drywall was removed.

[image]

Can I cut the excess rail (past the nail) so it fits the joists, which are 12" apart?
Or does that mean they're isn't enough space and I need to go smaller?

Comment: It looks like the rails should telescope (to allow for some variations in the spacing) if your spacing is on the short end I believe you can cut off the back en of the rails

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can trim the rails so they will fit in a tighter space. Look close there are usually indents in the metal to help with cutting and snapping the rail to a shorter length. This is part of a normal install.

Comment: +1 The [spec sheet](http://www.cooperindustries.com/content/dam/public/lighting/products/documents/halo/spec_sheets/halo-h5icat-adv140448-sss.pdf) shows that the rails can be shortened to fit into a 7 1/4" space.